# Image does not show up when rendering template on flask using blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to use flask bluprint to show a static image. This is the project tree:

```
.   
├── api.py  
├── __init__.py  
├── show.py  
├── static  
│   └── test.jpg  
└── templates  
    └── show.html
```

The content of `api.py`:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from api import show

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join('static')
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        UPLOAD_FOLDER = UPLOAD_FOLDER,
    )

    app.register_blueprint(show.bp)

    return app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And `show.py` is:

```
from flask import (Blueprint, render_template, current_app)
import os


bp = Blueprint('show', __name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='templates')

@bp.route('/show', methods=['POST'])
def show():
    image = os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'test.jpg')

    return render_template("show.html", in_image = image)
```

`show.html`;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Show</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ in_image }}" alt="Input Image">
</body>
</html>
```

And there is a `test.jpg` in static folder. When running the app

```
export FLASK_APP=api
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

only an icon like image with the tag "Input Image" shows up. Why actual image is not showing up here?

Comment: Can you add the `<img` HTML from the running page? this may give clues as to what `in_image` is, and how it may be wrong.

Comment: It shows the correct path to the image ``` <img src="static/test.jpg" alt="Input Image"> ```

Answer (score 1):

While trying to run the included app, I was facing import error. I updated the file structure and able to view the image from `static` folder. I changed the `request` method from `POST` to `GET` in `blueprints/show.py`.

File structure:

```
.
├── api.py
├── blueprints
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── show.py
├── static
│   └── penguins.png
└── templates
    └── show.html
```

`api.py`:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from blueprints.show import bp

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.join('static')
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        UPLOAD_FOLDER = UPLOAD_FOLDER,
    )
    app.register_blueprint(bp)
    return app

app = create_app()
```

`blueprints/__init__.py` is a blank file.

`blueprints/show.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, current_app
import os    

bp = Blueprint('show', __name__, static_folder='static',
               template_folder='templates')

@bp.route('/show')
def show():
    image = os.path.join(current_app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'penguins.png')
    return render_template("show.html", in_image = image)
```

`templates/show.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Show</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ in_image }}" alt="Input Image">
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: flask blueprint image load]

You can read more about structuring the blueprints resources in [official documentation on blueprint-resources](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/#blueprint-resources).

Comment: What import error do you get? The project directory is called api and so ```from api import show```

Comment: @Igneous, I did not know that. My project directory is `flask_blueprint_example`. I think, this was the reason behind the `import` error. Anyway, does the answer solve the problem?

Comment: I did not understand the need to change the project structure. The only related change seems to be the use of GET method, which also I am not clear about. Why the POST method does not work?

Comment: Project structure I have adapted is suggested in [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/#blueprint-resources). If `show` is a `POST` method, we can not hit the route from browser(`GET` request).

Comment: Using `GET` in the browser works, however there is another issue with `GET` in Postman where you get 200 back but the image preview does not still show! I guess that is a different question or related!?

Comment: I think that is a different question. Glad that `GET` request works :)